# What should I do when I encounter a user who reasks an identical question when their question is closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

A user asked a question [Weird behaviour from European Central Bank API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185917/weird-behaviour-from-european-central-bank-api) and it was closed as not appropriate for the site (missing debug details).  That user then immediately asked the same question again [European Central Bank API not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77186043/european-central-bank-api-not-working-as-expected).

While I know from parsing the question the same issue still remains (missing debug details) and I have flagged it as such, is there additional action I should be taking?

It seems like I should denote that they are doing something which feels to violate the spirit of the site.  If everyone just reasked their question whenever their question was closed it would lead to chaos, bloat the site with closed questions, and bloat all the review queues.  It seems like I should be doing something, but I'm not sure what.

It got closed as a duplicate (similar to Kevin's comment), so based on those folks it sounds like I should have marked it as a duplicate even though the duplicate doesn't have an answer.  Or does closure count as an answer?

Comment: if it is an exact duplicate by the same user, the duplicate close reason will work against it. Nothing more needs to be done

Comment: There is a fast path for duplicate closure to handle precisely this kind of situation. The question is now dupe-closed to make the original question the primary  one.

Comment: Thanks, I had been concerned about calling it a dupe since the flag says "and the other question is answered" it sounds like closure is considered an answer.. Thank you to you both for explaining

Comment: This is just a special case, specifically for this situation, ;) if a user reposts a question, we can close it as a dupe of the original without need for the original having an answer, or even caring if the original is closed. But we should use this "power" with consideration of whether or not the new question actually fixed the issue. If it did... it may be better to just move forward with the fixed question regardless of the fact that they should have instead edited the original.

Comment: should i delete my duplicate lol I had tried searching but couldn't find that post.

Comment: Nah, dupes are fine, as long as they can act as a signpost to the target.

Comment: @KevinB yes i surmised that from the reading I did while searching, which suggested that it's often better to reask properly and delete a dupe then to fix and pray for a reopen vote since something like only 2% of things get reopened. from that post about it. though it was a slightly controversial opinion.. I think it's less controversial if USER indeed deletes their initial question and indeed makes significant changes but its a risk either way as denoted in said post.

Comment: At least when the OP doesn't delete the prior question this is an option; it's far more frustrating when they delete and repost as the close/flag as duplicate option is no longer available.